# Using multiple Contexts in J2EE to connect to different data sources (Websphere)

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, application-server

I have a Java EE application that needs to connect to two databases. One is an in-memory database (H2) and one is a regular Oracle database.

I can set up the connection to the Oracle database in Websphere Application Server, put a reference in the ibm-web-bnd.xml, then use the following code to access it:

```
DataSource dataSource = null;
try 
{
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    // comp/env is for component-environment bindings, such as web application bindings
    // this allows us to change the name later in the binding (in the ibm-web-bnd.xml file), instead of here in the code.

    dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/refDB");
}
catch (NamingException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return dataSource.getConnection();
```

This works fine - InitialContext returns the WAS context I need, can find the data source and all is well.

However, I also want to be able to access an H2 database from the same application. Following a tutorial I found on pluralsight, it seems the way to do this is to import the tomcat jars, then create the context on-the-fly:

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

//"java:comp/env/jdbc/CacheDb" is the context that needs creating here.
ctx.createSubcontext("java:");
ctx.createSubcontext("java:comp");
ctx.createSubcontext("java:comp/env");
ctx.createSubcontext("java:comp/env/jdbc");

JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
dataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:cachedb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"); // don't delete the database when the last connection closes

ctx.bind("java:comp/env/jdbc/CacheDb", dataSource);
```

This code also works, if it's the only connection code in the application.

If I have an application where both are called at some point, I get errors like the following:

> SystemErr     R javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Unable to find
>   the InitialContextFactory
>   org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.

I then thought, OK, perhaps the `System.setProperty` code is causing the wrong context to be used for the Oracle lookup - so I tried specifying the WAS context specifically by using the following code before getting the InitialContext for the Oracle connection:

```
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.ibm.websphere.naming");
```

However, this gave me the same error, at the point where the H2 database context is configured.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong, or point me in the right direction for a solution? Thanks

Comment: The context already exists, so you shouldn't need to create sub-contexts. Can't you configure the h2 database the same way you configure your Oracle database?

Comment: I haven't tried. The tutorial I followed says not, but not why. I don't know how you would anyway, as it's in-memory (created by code rather than existing outside of the application) - so I couldn't set up a connection with the WAS console (could I?)

Comment: Actually, very good question. I haven't used h2 in WebSphere so I don't know. As long as it finds all classes I guess it should work. But as an alternative, you should at least not need to create the subcontext when it is already there. Can you remove those lines (`ctx.createSubcontext`) and see if you can bind the dataSource to the context?

Comment: Also, setting which classes you use for the `InitialContext` factory may screw things up. Can you get a specific `InitialContext` without having to change the system properties?

Comment: I don't know. `new InitialContext()` has an override that takes a hashtable

Comment: Right, so you can create a `Hashtable`object with the alternate properties set (meaning do not set them in the system properties, only in the `Hashtable`) and then pass that Hashtable in the `new InitialContext(hashtable)` call.

Comment: Something like they have done in example 2 here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/javax.naming.InitialContext but not using all the same properties, though. Just use yours.

Comment: OK, working through the suggestions one at a time then - the first one (just not creating the subcontexts) gives this error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource` - which is weird.

Comment: You are sure the class is on the classpath I assume, either in WAS or in the application?

Comment: yes, I've put the h2 jar in a folder in the application (/lib) and referenced it from the project (Build path -> Libraries -> Add JAR) in Eclipse.

Comment: I've now tried setting up the H2 connection in the admin console, and testing the connection there gives me `Failed to connect to the DataSource jdbc/CacheDB.  Encountered java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for  DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = 8,001.`

Comment: If you set it up in the WAS admin console I would guess it is not enough to have it on the classpath in the application. It must probably be on the applications server's classpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163264/discussion-between-simonalexander2005-and-danielbarbarian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using WebSphere Application Server traditional, and not Liberty.  Either can access an h2 database via a DataSource like any other JDBC compliant database.  It sounds like you've already configured a jdbc provider and DataSource for Oracle.  You just need to create and configure a user-defined jdbc provider and associated data source for h2 following the instructions in the [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_tccrtprovds.html).  Since you're configuring the resource references in your web.xml, let the app server do the work for you and simply inject both data sources into your application like

```
@Resource(lookup="jdbc/refDB")
DataSource oracleDS;
@Resource(lookup="jdbc/CacheDb")
DataSource h2DS;
```

You don't need to do a direct lookup in JNDI (nor should you) nor should you have to worry about the InitialContext.